# Major print formatting issues in ssrs

Tags: .net, oracle, reporting-services

So my whole team is stumped on this, generating an ssrs report from a package in oracle reporting services. When you go to preview it looks fine but in print preview the right third and bottom third of the page are cut off regardless of how I adjust the page size, margins, or anything else on the report, it prints exactly how it look in the print preview as well. If I export to a pdf it fills the whole page when I print. I have been messing with it for three days and I can not find anything in documentation about this problem.  Also if I put the laptop on a docking station with an extra large monitor the print preview will show the correct formatting AND print correctly, when I go back to a smaller monitor the formatting is wrong and printing is wrong again. Any ideas besides an exorcism?

Comment: Are you using the browser print button to print? And does the tool offer a print button at the top of the report?

Comment: I am viewing it in Visual Studio, when you are in the preview mode there is a print preview option. It looks fine in preview but when you switch to print preview is when the issue occurs. It is printing the same way from the browser, visual studio, and the user end as well, we launched it just to check. I have tried it on VS 2015 and 2017.

Comment: Are you consuming container whitespace? Print formatting is hard to get right. I always target PDF output when needing to print - then just print the PDF if needed. Body size and margins determine your “available space”. Everything in the report must fit inside (column groups and header/footer included) or the page will break.

Comment: They decided to send it to QA so hopefully someone else can figure it out. It was literally just shrinking my whole project down it was really weird, I wasn't getting a page break it just wouldn't fill the whole page.